# Differentiable iff unique subgradient

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}\cup \{ \infty \}$ be convex, $D:=Dom(f)$, $x\in D^o$.  Then f is differentiable at x iff $\partial f(x)=\{ d \}$ (a singleton), in which case $\nabla f(x)=d$. 
"$\rightarrow$" is shown in Ben Tal and Nemirovsky, "Lectures in Modern Convex Optimization". 
I'm curious about how to show "$\leftarrow$".  
Defns: $\partial f(x):=\{ d':f(y) \geq f(x)+d'^T (y-x) \forall y \in D \}$.  f is differentiable at $x\in D^o$ if $\exists$ a linear fn $Df_x:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $|f(x+h)-f(x)-Df_x (h)|\leq o(||h||_2)$, where $o(\cdot)$ is any fn s.t. $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{o(t)}{t}$=0.  $Df_x (h)=\nabla f(x)^T h$ if this fn exists. 
I also know that $\nabla f(x)\neq \emptyset$.  So I'm stuck on showing: if f is not differentiable at x, then $\partial f(x)$ has >1 element.

Comment: Do you know the characterization of the directional derivative by the subdifferential? I.e. $f'(x; h) = \max_{s \in \partial f(x)} s^\top h$, where $f'(x;h)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ at $x$ in direction $h$?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know about that.  Though if you had a justification in mind that uses that, I wouldn't mind.  Thx,